# Want to turn off "note" level messages in GCC

Tags: compiling, c, gcc, compiler

When I compile a C (no pluses) program using GCC, there are several levels of messages possible, like warning, error, and note.  The note messages are useless and distracting.  How do I make them go away using the command line?  (I don't use any sort of IDE.)

Example: /home/user/src9/AllBack3.c:129:9: **note:** each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in.

Comment: @mosvy, the man page makes `-fcompare-debug-second` sound a bit scary though: "When this option is passed to the compiler driver, it causes the first compilation to be skipped, which makes it useful for little other than debugging the compiler proper."

Comment: @mosvy I guess -fcompare-debug-second will have to do, if there's nothing else.  If you put that in the form of an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @ilkkachu notice that the second run of the compiler done by `-fcompare-debug` has nothing to do with the multiple compilation or optimization passes gcc may do -- as far as I can gather (I haven't used it myself), it's just a feature to debug the compiler itself (and create actionable bug reports).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pass the `-fcompare-debug-second` option to `gcc`.

---

gcc's internal API has a [`diagnostic_inhibit_note()`](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/diagnostic.h;hb=991edac437a3f0c1894517701f1bfa071d1e42ae#l273) function which turns any "note:" messages off, but that is only serviceable via the unexpected [`-fcompare-debug-second`](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/toplev.c;hb=991edac437a3f0c1894517701f1bfa071d1e42ae#l1319) command line switch, defined [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/common.opt;hb=991edac437a3f0c1894517701f1bfa071d1e42ae#l1145).

Fortunately, turning notes off is its *only* effect, unless the `-fcompare-debug` or the `-fdump-final-insns` options are also used, which afaik are only for debugging the compiler itself.

Comment: `-fcompare-debug-second` also inhibits messages coming from `#pragma message`. How to keep `#pragma message` messages?

Comment: `#pragma message` generates a note message. Consider using `#warning` instead.

Answer (score -3):

You can use `-w` which also suppresses warnings.

For GCC, `-w` will not suppress the note you mentioned, probably because it is shown instead of another error. clang's `-w` on the other hand suppresses that too.

Comment: But I don't want to suppress warnings.